# CommonJS or ES6 Module in server side works

Tags: es6-modules, commonjs

Recently I studied about CommonJS (CJS) and ECMAScript6 Module (ESM).

CJS is made for server-side JavaScript runtime, and ESM is made for client-side JavaScript runtime.

But ESM came out recently and it has better support for asynchronous module loading, tree shaking, etc.

**So, do you recommend CJS for server side work? or ESM?**